# Update IOT device parameters

Tags: architecture, iot, esp32, espressif-idf

I have IOT device based on Espressif ESP32 processor that communicates with owners mobile device via MQTT server. I found that sometimes I need to update IOT device parameters. Updates are initiated by system provider. For example, I need to change MQTT server. What is the best practice to update device configuration? Is it good style just to send message with parameters to IOT device via MQTT?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is actually a valid approach to send a message or command with parameters via MQTT in IoT environment. Here is how you can implement it.

1. Create a unique MQTT topic specific to update the configurations. For example, you can have a topic like, **devices/{device_id}/config**.
2. Define a format (Eg: JSON containing key-value pairs) for the configuration message.

> {"mqtt_server" : "your_server",
> "update_interval": 200,
> "parameter" : "new_value"}

3. Make sure that your ESP32 device subscribes to the configuration topic (devices/{device_id}/config) so that it can receive configuration updates.
4. You should also implement a logic in your ESP32 firmware to handle received configuration messages. You need to parse the message received and update the device's configuration accordingly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I saved the parameters using Preferences or You can write it to file and load it when device boot.